# Module compiled with Swift 5.1.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3 compiler Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

We are creating a custom framework using CI Jenkins build which is having Xcode 12 and try to import in another project which is using Xcode 11.6 and that shows the above error.

I am getting the above error while I am importing the above framework created by Xcode 12 but not working on Xcode 11.5.

Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 11.x uses different command tools which causes mentioned problem. You have to update the project to the 12.0 and then you can use your custom framework.

Or you can manually change Swift version in the project files of your framework project. However, there is no point why not update the project ¯_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: After setting  "BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION" to YES. Now I am getting the following error
"Module compiled with Swift 5.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.2.4 compiler: /Users/pratik/Desktop/IIIIII/Sample_ios/Lottie.framework/Modules/Lottie.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule"

In our custom framework, we are using Lottie pods for animation. My framework is created using Xcode 12.1 and I am using the framework in an app having Xcode 11.6. I want to know the above error is due to Lottie pods. Please let me know the steps to resolve this

Comment: Check if you are using Lottie version which supports Swift 5.3. Do you have `pod 'lottie-ios'` in your Podfile or specific version? Imho is always better to use latest version and dont specify the version.
Then use `pod update` if it fetch latest version. Then remove derivated data, clean build your repo and hopefully it works.